# Size and resize function of vector container in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I don't understand the next behavior with the functions size() and resize() in my program.

I create a vector of structs with 3 elements.

In the last part of the code, I use the function resize() in order to have only 2 elements. Then I assign again values to 3 elements getting a 3-element vector.

In the last part I can call the 3 elements of the vector vector_a so I understand I have a 3-element vector but the function size() is giving me as an output that I have 2 elements.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    struct struct_1
    {
        int variable_1;
        int variable_2;
    };

    std::vector<struct_1> vector_a;

    vector_a.push_back(struct_1());
    vector_a.push_back(struct_1());
    vector_a.push_back(struct_1());

    vector_a.resize(2);


    vector_a[0].variable_1 = 21;
    vector_a[0].variable_2 = 34;

    vector_a[1].variable_1 = 111;
    vector_a[1].variable_2 = 764;

    vector_a[2].variable_1 = 5656;
    vector_a[2].variable_2 = 5666764;

    std::cout << "size    " << vector_a.size() << std::endl;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Indexing using [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) have no bounds-checking. Use [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) if you want bounds-checking. And you *have* two elements in the vector, that what the [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) call does.

Comment: _"In the last part I can call the 3 elements of the vector vector_a so I understand I have a 3-element vector"_ No. Just because the compiler doesn't stop you from doing something doesn't mean that thing is OK to do. C++ doesn't proactively protect everyone from all mistakes, because that would result in pointlessly slower code for people who already know how to avold those mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

The `operator[]` directly accesses memory and doesn't check for the bounds, so referencing index 2 while the size is only 2 is invalid.

A related problem sometimes seen in code is developers calling `vector.reserve(10)` and then indexing elements 0 to 9 (instead of `reserve` they should call `resize`).

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like you wouldn't get exception out of range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/) if you keep accessing elements in this way... try .at() method if you want to get exception.

> A similar member function, vector::at, has the same behavior as this operator function, except that vector::at is bound-checked and signals if the requested position is out of range by throwing an out_of_range exception.
>
> Portable programs should never call this function with an argument n that is out of range, since this causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To add the previous answers

> Then I assign again values to 3 elements getting a 3-element vector.

You are not, from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) the description of  `std::vector::operator[]`

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No
>   bounds checking is performed.

This operator does not add an element to the vector if you are accessing an out of bound element (it is not like an [std::map](http://std::map))